# Hadoop - PIG loop on XML nodes using XPath

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, apache-pig

I have a XML file

```
<Superfoo>
<foo>
    <Number>1</Number>  
    <childfoo>20</childfoo>
</foo>
<foo>
    <Number>2</Number>  
    <childfoo>10</childfoo>
</foo>
<foo>
    <Number>3</Number>  
    <childfoo>29</childfoo>
</foo>
</Superfoo>
```

My requirement is to loop on  nodes. I don't want to hard code them as it can vary from one XML to another XML. Is there any way we can achieve it using **`PIG XPath`**.

```
A =  LOAD 'foo.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Superfoo') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'Superfoo/foo/Number'), XPath(x, 'Superfoo/foo/childfoo');
dump B;
```

I tried with above code but it return only 1 row but with Foreach it should return all the rows of  node.

Is it possible that we can do it thru Hive using loop? Seems difficult to me....

Any pointers????

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below.

```
A =  LOAD 'foo.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('foo') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'foo/Number'), XPath(x, 'foo/childfoo');

dump B;
```

**`Dump B`** will produce output as below:

(1,20)

(2,10)

(3,29)

Comment: Any suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921201/hadoop-load-hive-tables-using-pig